# How do we pronounce the acronym CMYK?

Tags: pronunciation, acronyms, initialisms

How does one pronounce the acronym [*CMYK*, in the color model sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model).

If there is more than one pronunciation, how popular is each of them?

Comment: I usually pronounce it /smik/ (to rhyme with ‘stick’), but that might be influenced by my working with printers and designers who speak Danish and therefore pronounce it /smyk/.

Comment: In Finland, I've heard it pronounced (when speaking English) "smook" (/smʊk/), rhymes with "nook".

Answer (score 32):

See-Em-Why-Kay.

I just asked the designers here and they do nothing other than pronounce the letters.  If they need to term it they use "Four colour process".

Answer (score 5):

I think this kind of acronym is usually [pronounced as separate letters](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/CMYK.html) - "C, M, Y, K". I've also found a [source](http://www.forvo.com/word/cmyk/) (first speaker) where after conventional pronunciation another variant is given - /smaɪk/.

Comment: +1 for separate letters, smaik, I have yet to come accross.

Answer (score 0):

I have always told my students to pronounce it as the letters indicate, in other words as:  c-mike (CMYK). This seems to help them remember the four process colors.